# Conditional Formatting With Nested If Statements [excel]

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I have a PivotTable that, for this example's sake, has three columns:

Column B contains non-negative number values.

Column D contains non-negative number values.

Column C shows the percent of change from Column D to Column B (ie, D1=1 and B1=2, C1=100%).

I have a Conditional Formatting rule set up so that if any value in Column C is greater than 10%, the cell is highlighted in red.  However, this does not work when a cell in Column D has a value of zero, and the corresponding cell in Column B has a value higher than zero, because the result would be infinity.

My goal is to set up a rule so that if any cell in Column D has a value of zero, and any cell (on the same row) in Column B has a value greater than zero, the corresponding row in Column C will still be highlighted in red.  Since I have non-negative numbers in my data, technically as long as Column D is zero and Column B is not zero, this would satisfy the formula.

I've tried using the following formatting rule to apply to Column C but have not been successful.  I'm sure this could be also be accomplished using nested IF statements:

```
IF(D$=0 AND(B$<>0), TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: Is this a `VBA` question or do you require a `Conditional Formatting` formula?

Comment: This does not make sense. You firstly ask that the cell should be highlighted red if cell c is greater than +10%, and you say this is your goal. You then say that you want it to be highlighted red if D is 0 and and B is greater than 0 it also be highlighted red. This would change your criteria to: column C >+10% AND column C<0%. As per @SkipIntro, this is conditional formatting question

Comment: @skipIntro Conditional Formatting seems like the most straightforward approach, but if there's a way to do this in VBA I am open to using that as well.

Comment: Also i tried this: conditional format via formula: `Formula: = $C1>10%`

Comment: @mo.h I'm trying to get the cell highlighted specifically if D$=0 and B$>0, which I assume could be added as an additional rule to Column C.

Comment: Try this formula "=And(D1=0,B1>0)". Before doing make sure you select the relevant column C range. If the first row is not C1 then adjust formula accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AND` in Excel is used differently... it works like this: and(condition1,condition2). So your code should be formatted like this:

`IF(AND(D$=0,(B$<>0)), TRUE, FALSE)`

But it works differently in conditional formatting... so what you do is select the range, but make sure to note what cell is highlighted:
[image]

As you can see, you don't have to worry about the TRUE FALSE conditions... just the logical test is enough. So if you follow my screenshot, your formula should be:

`=AND(D4=0,B4<>0)`

(I assume your data starts in row 4... this should be the row that is HIGHLIGHTED in your selected range. In my case it's row 4.

Comment: Amit, thank you so much!  This did the trick.  I think I was also thrown off by the $, I had thought that C$ would tell Excel to look at the whole column.  I need to read a good book on Excel.

Comment: nonsense. All you need is practice. There's only one way to learn and that is to make many many mistakes. Many many maaany mistakes. :) I hope you continue to err!

Answer (score 0):

Conditional formatting of column C, rows 1 to 50:

Applies to: =$C$1:$C$50

Format values when this formula is true:
=AND($D1=0, $B1>0)

If your line separator is semicolon, not comma use this instead:
=AND($D1=0; $B1>0)